The connection either timed out or was lost
I have problem connect to analysis server through application. Getting the error shown here, and we recently updated from .NET 5.0 to .NET 7.0. The database server is running Windows 2019.

Message: The connection either timed out or was lost.
Source: AdomdClientNetCore
Exception Type: Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.AdomdConnectionException
StackTrace:
at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.XmlaClient.EndRequest(Boolean useBinaryXml)
at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.XmlaClient.EndRequest()
at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.XmlaClient.SendMessage(Boolean endReceivalIfException, Boolean readSession, Boolean readNamespaceCompatibility)
at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.XmlaClient.Discover(String requestType, String requestNamespace, ListDictionary properties, IDictionary restrictions, Boolean sendNamespacesCompatibility, IDictionary requestProperties)
at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.XmlaClient.SupportsProperty(String propName)
at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.XmlaClient.Connect(ConnectionInfo connectionInfo, Boolean beginSession)
at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.AdomdConnection.XmlaClientProvider.Connect(Boolean toIXMLA)
at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.AdomdConnection.XmlaClientProvider.Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.AdomdConnection.IXmlaClientProviderEx.ConnectXmla()
at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.AdomdConnection.ConnectToXMLA(Boolean createSession, Boolean isHTTP)  Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.SyncObjectResultExecutor.Execute(ActionContext actionContext, IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|26_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
Inner Exception Message: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host..
Inner Exception Source: System.Net.Sockets
Inner Exception StackTrace:    at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
at System.IO.BufferedStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.DimeRecord.ForceRead(Stream stream, Byte[] buffer, Int32 length)
at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.DimeRecord.ReadHeader()
at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.DimeRecord..ctor(Stream stream)
at Microsoft.Analyyour textsisServices.AdomdClient.DimeReader.ReadRecord()
at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.TcpStream.GetResponseDataType()

We are using .NET 7.0.
Note: the analysis server connects regular .NET application not .NET 7.0.
I have checked multiple blocking issue but could not identify the reason. That connection has been working on some servers. Issue getting specific server not all. How to resolve that issue?
